# Generate portlet instance id liferay

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, liferay-velocity

I'm building some pages in liferay 6.1 GA3, so recently I was in need of embedding liferay web content portlets in an other web content portlet for this I use something like :

```
<div class="somecontent_stuff">
        <runtime-portlet name="56" instance="hj33" queryString=""/>
</div>
<div class="some other content">
        <runtime-portlet name="56" instance="ze33" queryString=""/>
</div>

<div id="part_right">
    <runtime-portlet name="56" instance="nj33" queryString=""/>
</div>
```

And this is working perfectly fine, but when I use my web content in multiple page I have the change instance id manually and for every page, which is exhausting and risky (because I have lot of pages like this ).

Is there any way to generate this code automatically ?

Answer (score 0):

Capture the instance id of your embedded portlet using a **web form**. See [this](http://www.liferay.com/web/barrie.selack/blog/-/blogs/embedding-a-portlet-in-web-content) for more info

Comment: Yes this a solution, and this what I used to do BTW, but imagine every time I create an article I should enter a random string, nothing just to put blocs in their places. I was wondering if there is a method to generate it automatically, something that do the same thing when you drag the WC to the page.